# Como comparar duas ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, imagine que existam duas `ViewModel`:

```
public CustoViewModel cvm = new CustoViewModel();
public CustoViewModel custoViewModel= new CustoViewModel();
```

E que cada `ViewModel` tenha seus valores separados

```
cvm.cod = 10;
cvm.desc = "Teste";

custoViewModel.cod = 11;
custoViewModel.desc = "Teste";
```

Eu estou fazendo a comparação a baixo e sei que me retorna false

```
if(!cvm.Equals(custoViewModel))
{
     //Comentario
}
```

O que quero saber é o seguinte: se for diferente, eu preciso pegar o campo que é diferente da seguinte maneira:

```
cvm.cod = custoViewModel.cod;
```

Isso nesse exemplo se torna fácil pois eu coloquei apenas dois campos, mas e quando tem mais campos, então, para finalizar: Existe alguma maneira de pegar os campos diferentes sem ter que ficar fazendo vários `if` ? (***Alguma maneira da que seja diferente da mostrada a baixo***)

```
if(!cvm.Equals(custoViewModel))
{
     if(cvm.cod == custoViewModel.cod)
     {
          cvm.cod = custoViewModel.cod;
     }
     if(cvm.desc== custoViewModel.desc)
     {
          cvm.desc= custoViewModel.desc;
     }
}
```

Comment: você fazer isso usando reflection

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada e ver como funciona @RicardoPontual

Comment: Porque precisa fazer isso qual a razão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode sobrescrever o  metodo Equals da classe CustoViewModel

```
    public override bool Equals (object o)  
    {
        if (this.Id == o.Id && this.Nome == o.Nome)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

o retorno do método acima, seria true para caso os atributos das instancias sejam iguais, caso queira comparar somente o id pode retirar `&& this.Nome == o.Nome`, ai então coparará somente o id da entidade

mais informações 
http://gabsferreira.com/a-maneira-certa-de-comparar-objetos-em-c/